# ActiveRecord uniqueness validation and orphaned has_many associations in Rails 4 using << syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm having a strange issue with validates_uniqueness_of on a simple has_many association. Here is a simplified version of the models:

`#profile.rb`

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :majors, -> { uniq }, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end
```

`#major.rb`

```
class Major < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :profile
  ...
end
```

The strange behavior appears when I add associations from the rails console:

```
> Profile.first.majors << Major.create(:name => 'basketweaving')
```

The first one is added as expected. Then I run it again...

```
> Profile.first.majors << Major.create(:name => 'basketweaving')
```

The second one returns a successful result with no rollback or uniqueness validation error. I would expect the error and rollback on this insert and I am left with the records shown below. Notice there is nil profile_id on the second record but for some reason it is still being saved.

```
[
[0] #<Major:0x007ff72bdbfce8> {
             :id => 20,
           :name => "Finance",
     :profile_id => 5,
    :school_code => nil,
     :created_at => Tue, 02 Feb 2016 03:48:56 UTC +00:00,
     :updated_at => Tue, 02 Feb 2016 03:48:56 UTC +00:00
},
[1] #<Major:0x007ff72bdbfba8> {
             :id => 21,
           :name => "Finance",
     :profile_id => nil,
    :school_code => nil,
     :created_at => Tue, 02 Feb 2016 03:48:58 UTC +00:00,
     :updated_at => Tue, 02 Feb 2016 03:48:58 UTC +00:00
}
]
```

The third time I run the command:

```
 > Profile.first.majors << Major.create(:name => 'basketweaving')
```

I get the rollback I would expect but it appears to be rolling back because the Major with :name => 'basketweaving' and a nil profile_id is a duplicate. This does not seem intuitive and I am ending up with those orphaned records. Is there a better way to do this? Should I just do something like:

```
unless Profile.first.majors.where(:name => 'basketweaving').exists?
    Profile.first.majors << Major.create(:name => 'basketweaving')
end
```

Comment: Are you saving `Profile.first` after each push?

Comment: no, it's not being changed, although << *should* cause the association to autosave with the proper profile_id

Comment: does `Major` validate the presence of `profile`?

Comment: regardless, what you really should be doing is: `Profile.first.majors.create(:name => 'basketweaving')`

Comment: I agree. Still unclear on why I'm getting a weird behavior from the other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `Profile.first.majors << Major.create(:name => 'basketweaving')`

...is performed in 2 steps:

1. `Major.create(:name => 'basketweaving')`

This creates a new `Major` object, but it does not yet have an association with a profile.  Therefore, `profile_id` is nil.

2. `Profile.first.majors << (newly created Major object)`

This takes the newly created object and attempts to add it to the first `Profile`'s collection of majors.  It does so by changing the `Major` object's `profile_id` to match that of the `Profile` object.

The first time you run it, steps 1 and 2 are both successful.  But here's what happens the second time:

1. The `Major` object is created with `nil` `profile_id`
2. It does not succeed in adding the `Major` object to the collection, because of the uniqueness validation. There is already a `Major` object with the same name and `profile_id`.  While there is no rollback notice, it does return `false` instead of returning the collection.  So the `Major` object's `profile_id` remains `nil`.

...and the third time:

1. The `Major` object is NOT created, again because of the uniqueness validation.  There is already a `Major` object of that name with a `profile_id` of `nil`.

**Suggestions**

Because of this quirk, I would recommend adding to the collection like this: `Profile.first.majors.create(:name => 'basketweaving')`.  That way, you're calling one single method on the collection itself.

Also, if you want to be sure that a `Major` object never has a `nil` `profile_id`, set a presence validation on `Major`: `validates :profile, presence: true`

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!